# How to export Json data in xlsx format sheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

> Hi i have a nested  json  object data in that i do have 3 objects/more
>   than that, its depends on saving the data it is going to increase for
>   some employees and not i need to export my json data in xlsx format in
>   this way. i do have table structure here i need to export my json data in this format, can any one help out how to do this one, since from past 3 days im trying to achieve this one but unable to do.. please make fiddle/plunker and send it to me it would be grate help for me, Thanks in Advance.

export.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
   <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <button ng-click="exportData()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;margin-right:30px; margin-bottom:30px;">Export&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
            </div>
     </html>
```

export.js

```
var app=angular.module('myCtrl',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.data = [
  {

    "InverterId": Inverter,
    "LstRecords": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "InverterId": 1,
        "TimeofReading": "20170220",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 32,
        "InverterId": 1,
        "TimeofReading": "20170221",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 12
      },
      {
        "Id": 32,
        "InverterId": 1,
        "TimeofReading": "20170221",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 12
      }
    ]
  }
]

});
$scope.exportData = function () {
    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [$scope.data] );  
};
```

> i need to display my data in xlsx export sheet in this way in fututer
>   inverters may increas but format should be same, it has to display
>   like this only.. i have tried in 4 different ways but got reject, can
>   any one help me out in this since from past 2 days im stucking in this
>   issue fully blind on this topic please make fiddle and send it would be
>   grate help for me please,I have tried all the ways and googled also please some one help in this out put. Thanks in advance

Comment: This shouldn't be responsibility of AngularJS but a web service (which would be consumed by AngularJS).

Comment: Im sorry to say, i have ask them who is creating the web API, every one is telling in angularjs only we need to do.. any idea please do it and give since i tried all the ways from my side, this is only im unable to do.. please let me know.

Comment: else in javascript we can do means that is also k but it should export in the same way as i have given

Comment: can any one let me know this answer please

Comment: I agree this isn't the responsibility of Angular, but nevertheless there are libraries to handle this sort of thing. Check out this documentation: https://libraries.io/bower/js-xlsx

Comment: how abt in javascript wre we can do this...

Comment: i have googled a lot for this solution but no were im getting this solution